# How to organize exchanges and queues in rabbitmq to use with async CQRS buses

Tags: events, rabbitmq, cqrs, rabbitmq-exchange

I'm scaffolding my backend application and I want to use CQRS and rabbitmq with it (I'm pretty new to rabbitmq).  For that, I have specified different **vhosts** for my *prod* and *dev* environments, but I'm not sure how to use **exchanges** and **queues** for *command*, *events* and *query* buses.

Should I use just **one exchange**, named for example *CQRS* **and three different queues** for *commands*, *queries* and *events*?

Or maybe should I use **three different exchanges** (named *query_bus*, *command_bus* and *event_bus*) and inside each one **map one queue to every possible command query and event** using *routing keys*?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to queue the commands? and queries? any specific reason?

Comment: These would be async buses, it would help my app performance because large time consuming tasks (queries or commands), could be processed in some other machine for example. My app would just post an specific command or query (DTOs) to this queue and once it's processed it would gather the response if any, or notify it there was an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have separate queues for different content (commands, queries...).

Because then its easier to see if the command or query side is lagging/slow by examining the length of each queue. The queue length gives you nice charts for your dashboard.

Comment: And all these queues should be in the same exchange, right?

Comment: i think the same is a good starting point. Monitoring and plotting the queue lengths over time is a really interesting chart to have....